# Implement a calender with Ruby and Javascript in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, calendar

I'm trying to implement a calendar with Ruby and Javascript in Rails. I'm using a calendar helper that creates a calendar with given year and month and events as parameters (`<%= calendar(:year => 2012, :month => 4, :events => @events %>`).

I also have three buttons next, today and previous with which the user should be able to navigate the calendar with. I am also going to implement some js that makes it possible to select dates in the calendar. So what I would like to do is to insert the calendar in the DOM with javascript in order to generate a new calendar when the user clicks one of the buttons. That way I will be able to control the behavior of the buttons and add the select functionality.

The problem is that I can't just insert my erb code in a javascript plus I'm not even sure it's the right way to go? Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using already existing tools, like [jQuery DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)?

Comment: Yes, but none fit my needs so I decided to create my own helper.. Is there anything more I could clarify?

Answer (score 0):

How about the gem Chronic? It is a natural language parser for times